# Adding new payment method on Magento Community 1.6.2

Tags: magento, module, payment

I'm developing an e-commerce site using magento community 1.6.2. I need to use Knet as my payment gateway (Kuwait local payment system). They use a php-java bridge to connect their system with magento. Magento wiki tutorials are not helping, they are not showing the admin side.

How can I add this payment method to magento.

Comment: This company has support for Magento and KNet:  http://www.shrishtionline.com/prestashop-module-magento-extension-for-knet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Developing a Magento extension is not an easy task, and payment gateway integrations are not easy to work with.

I can recommend you to hire a professional to do the job for you and you just install the module on your Magento store.

Regards.